# XML parsing using but Element Names are Dynamic

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
Simple XMLElement Object
(    
         [IpStatus] => 1    
         [ti_pid_20642] => SimpleXmlElement Object    
               (
```

I have a SimpleXMLElment in above format and this XML is generated at run time and it's node values like `ti_pid_20642` are partly dnymaic, for example `ti_pid_3232`, `ti-pid_2323`, `ti_pid_anyumber`.

My question is how can I get these nodes values and it's children using PHP?

Comment: You get it just like any other node with simplexml. If you don't know how that is done, searching this website should help you. I write it that way because from your question it is not clear what you've done so far, so it's clear what your *programming*  question is. Where do you hit the road-block? I also edited your question, check the formatting tools.

Comment: i am searched but i am not find any solution , i am get node value like $xml->ti_pid_20642 , but my question is "ti_pid_20642" this value generate in runtime and i am not know node name , so how i am get node value ?

Comment: i think you don't understand my question, my simple question is i am not known node name so how i am get it's value ?

Comment: if you also don't know , why you give me -1 ?

Comment: Probably because it's not clear what you do with your code. As this is a website about programming questions, it's generally expected to see some code the question is about. In your case: A short example of the XML, the 3-7 lines of code you use so far (that do not work for you) and such stuff (I did not downvote you, just FYI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all node names that are used in an XML *string* with SimpleXML you can use the `SimpleXMLIterator`:

```
$tagnames = array_keys(iterator_to_array(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new SimpleXMLIterator($string)
        , RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    )
));

print_r($tagnames);
```

Which could give you exemplary (you did not give any XML in your question, [Demo](http://codepad.org/QWhqD3sh)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => IpStatus
    [1] => ti_pid_20642
    [2] => dependend
    [3] => ti-pid_2323
    [4] => ti_pid_anyumber
    [5] => more
)
```

If you have problems to provide a string that contains valid XML, take your existing SimpleXMLelement and [create an XML string out of it](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml):

```
$string = $simpleXML->asXML();
```

However,  if you like to get all tagnames from a SimpleXML object but you don't want to convert it to a string, you can create a recursive iterator for `SimpleXMLElement` as well:

```
class SimpleXMLElementIterator extends IteratorIterator implements RecursiveIterator
{
    private $element;

    public function __construct(SimpleXMLElement $element) {
        parent::__construct($element);
    }

    public function hasChildren() {
        return (bool)$this->current()->children();
    }

    public function getChildren() {
        return new self($this->current()->children());
    }
}
```

The usage of it would be similar ([Demo](http://codepad.org/po8qVodV)):

```
$it      = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXMLElementIterator($xml), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$tagnames = array_keys(iterator_to_array($it));
```

It just depends on what you need.

This becomes less straight forward, with namespaced elements. Depending if you want to get the local names only or the namspace names or even the namespace URIs with the tagnames.

The given `SimpleXMLElementIterator` could be changed to support the iteration over elements across namespaces, by default simplexml only offers traversal over elements in the default namespace:

```
/**
 * SimpleXMLElementIterator over all child elements across namespaces 
 */
class SimpleXMLElementIterator extends IteratorIterator implements RecursiveIterator
{
    private $element;

    public function __construct(SimpleXMLElement $element) {
        parent::__construct(new ArrayIterator($element->xpath('./*')));
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->current()->getName();
    }

    public function hasChildren() {
        return (bool)$this->current()->xpath('./*');
    }

    public function getChildren() {
        return new self($this->current());
    }
}
```

You would then need to check for the namespace per each element- As an example a modified XML document making use of namespaces:

```
<root xmlns="namspace:default" xmlns:ns1="namespace.numbered.1">
    <ns1:IpStatus>1</ns1:IpStatus>
    <ti_pid_20642>
        <dependend xmlns="namspace:depending">
            <ti-pid_2323>ti-pid_2323</ti-pid_2323>
            <ti_pid_anyumber>ti_pid_anyumber</ti_pid_anyumber>
            <more xmlns:ns2="namspace.numbered.2">
                <ti_pid_20642 ns2:attribute="test">ti_pid_20642</ti_pid_20642>
                <ns2:ti_pid_20642>ti_pid_20642</ns2:ti_pid_20642>
            </more>
        </dependend>
    </ti_pid_20642>
</root>
```

Combined with the update `SimpleXMLIterator` above the following example-code demonstrates the new behavior:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXMLElementIterator($xml), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$count = 0;
foreach ($it as $name => $element) {
    $nsList = $element->getNamespaces();
    list($ns, $nsUri) = each($nsList);
    printf("#%d:  %' -20s  %' -4s  %s\n", ++$count, $name, $ns, $nsUri);
}
```

Output ([Demo](http://codepad.org/zc7rrgz6)):

```
#1:  IpStatus              ns1   namespace.numbered.1
#2:  ti_pid_20642                namspace:default
#3:  dependend                   namspace:depending
#4:  ti-pid_2323                 namspace:depending
#5:  ti_pid_anyumber             namspace:depending
#6:  more                        namspace:depending
#7:  ti_pid_20642                namspace:depending
#8:  ti_pid_20642          ns2   namspace.numbered.2
```

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but this return following error .
String could not be parsed as XML --- FAtAl ERROR

Comment: Provide a string that is valid XML. Otherwise this will always fail. If you have got a [`SimpleXMLElement` object](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement), you need to get its XML first.

Comment: Thank you , your this message [Provide a string that is valid XML. Otherwise this will always fail. If you have got a SimpleXMLElement object, you need to get its XML first.] is very help full  to me .

Comment: @AdomsAdoms: I now added a `SimpleXMLElementIterator` that is able to iterator over a SimpleXML object directly. It comes with two variants, the first one is following SimpleXML's standard traversal, the second one allows to traverse all xml elements regardless of the namespace. I leave this for future reference, I don't know if you understand it at all. But maybe it's helpful.