# In PHP is there a parser that automatically parse XML using XSD file?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xsd

I need to  echo the content of XML documents. Not the XML source but the output. I have many XML files, all of them has an XSD file.

How can I parse them using these XSD files? Is it possible somehow?

(When I'm open the files in browser (XML or XSD), a text appears at the top of source code saying "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.")

Comment: You can validate the XML file against an XSD file.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What does parsing that mean? And which of the similar questions already asked didn't work for you and why? Answering these questions should clarify more clearly what you've looking for.

Comment: it turned out that xsl is for the xml docs layout, and not the xsd... so I could use that. Its not really what im looking for, but it is good for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [XmlReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) extensions

- [`DOMDocument::schemaValidate`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php)  —  Validates a document based on a schema
- [`XMLReader::setSchema`](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.setschema.php) — Validate document against XSD

Also, Check - http://github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You can use simpleXML of php like below:

```
<?php 
$string = <<<XML 
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document> 
    <cmd>login</cmd> 
    <login>Richard</login> 
</document> 
XML; 


$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
print_r($xml); 
$login = $xml->login; 
print_r($login); 
$login = (string) $xml->login; 
print_r($login); 
?> 

Expected result: 
---------------- 
SimpleXMLElement Object 
( 
    [cmd] => login 
    [login] => Richard 
) 
Richard 
Richard
```

For more information you can see :http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I tried this but it assumes that I know the XMLs structure, but i want it automatically to do...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221155/xml-parsing-using-but-element-names-are-dynamic